# ¿Porque mi filtro de búsqueda falla?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hice un `listbox` que muestre todos los pdf y jpg de una carpeta específica.

Pero tengo problemas al hacer una búsqueda desde el cuadro de texto. Si yo pongo de carácter "**5**", por ejemplo, de resultado me arroja todos los archivos que incluya un 5 en su nombre y **no únicamente** los que comienzan así.

¿Donde tengo el problema desde acá?

```
 private void txtbuscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listpdf.Items.Clear();
        string directorio = "\\" + "\\" + "11.16.22.2\\escan$";
        DirectoryInfo lista = new DirectoryInfo(@directorio);
        foreach (var item in lista.GetFiles().Where(s => s.Name.EndsWith(".pdf") || s.Name.EndsWith(".jpg")))
        {

            if (item.Name.ToLower().Contains(txtbuscar.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                listpdf.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: es que estas usando `Contains` en esta linea `item.Name.ToLower().Contains(txtbuscar.Text.ToLower()`, prueba con `StartsWith`, por ejemplo `item.Name.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith(txtbuscar.Text.ToLower().Trim())` ahi tambien le agrego `Trim` para quitar los espacios antes y despues

Comment: investigando no me di cuenta que Contains era lo mismo que el %LIKE%. Tampoco tenia idea del StartsWith. Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitanas obtener la lista de archivos de una carpeta por extension podrias usa

```
string directorio = @"\\11.16.22.2\escan$";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directorio);

var query = from f in files
              let name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)
            where (f.EndsWith(".pdf") || f.EndsWith(".jpg")) 
                  && name.StartsWith(txtbuscar.Text)
            select name;

foreach(var item in query){
  listpdf.Items.Add(item);
}
```

creo que al usar la notacion linq el codigo queda mucho mas prolijo

[Directory.GetFiles(String)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_)